# When i make a restcall with powershell it does not consider the odata filters

Tags: powershell, api, odata

I already try in these ways:

1.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://url.com:1111/api/User?$filter=email%20eq%20%27josue.ramirez@testmail.com%27" -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $header  -UseBasicParsing
```

2.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://url.com:1111/api/User?$filter=email eq 'josue.ramirez@testmail.com'" -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $header  -UseBasicParsing
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of a GET method.

```
$exampleGET=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri www.google.com -Method get
```

If you want to explore the result, just open the variable `write-output $exampleGET`
The variable is `HtmlWebResponseObject` there for an Object.
You can explore the object further down like so :

```
$exampleGET.forms
```

This will give you the form provided by that site.

If you want to know more about `invoke-WebRequest` you can check on Microsoft : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6

There is also `Invoke-RestMethod` here : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6

Have in mind that working with API's and sites, can be very different from each other.

Comment: I found the answer, the $ is consider as a special character in Powershell, so if use a $ inside " " it will refer as a variable that is not defined and it will not print anything. So What i did is print the URL with simple ' '. Like this   $URL = 'https:/url:1111/api/User?$filter=contains(email,' 'josue.ramirez@epicor.com' ')'   and then use that $url when i make the request like this invoke-webrequest -uri $url -Method GET

Comment: Again, different API's different requirements. If you wanna go to the next level, you might want to explore how to query the API with a`$body`

Comment: I cant due to the endpoint will only returns the first 100 values, thats why i need to enter odata filters to bring the specific data am requesting

Answer (score 0):

I guess that using a variable in a the URI string is causing the problem.
**Try**: Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://url.com:1111/api/User?**`**$filter=email eq 'josue.ramirez@testmail.com'" -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $header  -UseBasicParsing